# 403 Forbidden in nginx/1.12.0 after Install SSL (CentOS6)

Tags: wordpress, ssl, nginx, centos6

I'm install Wordpress in CentOS 6 (Nginx)
After installed SSL Certificat I stumble
In error 403 Forbidden nginx/1.12.0
?

/etc/nginx/Conf.d/ssl.conf

```
 server {
    listen 443;
    server_name Sitename.com www.Sitename.com;

    ssl on;
    sslcertificate /etc/ssl/serverchain.crt;
    sslcertificatekey /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

    accesslog /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.access.log;
    errorlog /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.error.log;

    location / {

    root /var/www/;
    index index.html;
    }

    }
```

But when you change

```
location / {

root /var/www/;
index index.html;
}
```

To

```
 location / {

root /var/www/html;
index index.html index.htm index.php;

}
```

When entering the site the page is loaded
What the solution ?